# how to renew access token with gdata python

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, gdata, picasa

I'm trying to switch my picasa app to oauth2.0 .

```
    from gdata.gauth import OAuth2Token
    token = OAuth2Token(
        client_id=client_id,
        client_secret=client_secret,
        scope=scope,
        user_agent=useragent)

    url = token.generate_authorize_url(redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob', approval_prompt='force', access_type="offline")

    print url

    code = raw_input('code:')
    token.get_access_token(code)
```

And then, I get access token

```
access_token = token.access_token
```

When I want to get albums :

```
albums = gd_client.GetFeed("https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default?access_token="+access_token)
print albums
```

Here's the problem. The access token will expired in short time and I'll get error message

> (403) Token invalid - Invalid token: Token not found -- Forbidden

I tried many way but no luck.
Please help me to fix this. Thanks